# Having an issue with $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

So I'm trying to build a basic file upload with the form below. However when I try to access the variables form the 'uploadVideo.php' script which is set in the action it doesn't work. For example, I am trying to get the title by using $_POST['title'] and nothing shows up. Probably it's a small bug but I have been struggling with it for a long time and I can't find the problem.

```
<form role="form" action="php/functions/uploadVideo.php" method="POST"
                      onsubmit="return checkFile(2097152)">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="videoTitle">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="videoTitle" placeholder="Enter a title..." required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="description">Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="videoDescription" rows="5" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="videoTags">Tags</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="videoTags" placeholder="Separate tags with a commma..." required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                        <input type="file" id="videoFile" required>
                    </div>
                    <center><button id="upload-video-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button></center>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give your input elements `name` attributes. The name is required for the control to be successful (i.e. submitted at all) and determines the key used for the `$_POST` array when PHP parses the form data.

Comment: Shit, I put id instead of name ... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

for each input you need NAME attribute

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="videoTitle" id="videoTitle" placeholder="Enter a title..." required>
```

and the access it with $_POST['videoTitle'].

Answer (score 0):

You need the input name parameter:
here's the correct code

```
    <form role="form" action="php/functions/uploadVideo.php" method="POST"
                          onsubmit="return checkFile(2097152)">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="videoTitle">Title</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="videoTitle" name="videoTitle" placeholder="Enter a title..." required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="description">Description</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="videoDescription" name="videoDescription" rows="5" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="videoTags">Tags</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="videoTags" name="videoTags" placeholder="Separate tags with a commma..." required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                            <input type="file" id="videoFile" name="videoFile" required>
                        </div>
                        <center><button id="upload-video-btn" name="upload-video-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button></center>
                    </form>
```